# Excel CUBEVALUE & CUBESET count records greater than a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, mdx

I am writing a series of queries to my workbook's data model to retrieve the number of documents by `Category_Name` which are greater than a certain numbers of days old (e.g. `>=650`).

Currently this formula (entered in celll `C3`) returns the correct number for a single `Days Old` value (`=3`).

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
            "[Measures].[Count of Docs]",
            "[EDD_Report].[Category_Name].&["&$B2&"]",
            "[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[34]")
```

How do I return the number of documents for `Days Old` values `>=650`?

The worksheet looks like:

```
     A            B             C
 1  Date        PL        Count of Docs
 2  10/1/2018   ALD             3
 3  ...
```

**UPDATE:** As suggested in @ama 's answer below, the expression in step B did not work.

However, I created a subset of the `Days Old` values using

```
 =CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
          "{[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[all].[650]:[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All].[3647]}")
```

The cell containing this cubeset is referenced as the third `Member_expression` of the original CUBEVALUE formula. The limitation is now that the values for the beginning and end must be members of the `Days Old` set.

This is limiting, in that, I was hoping for a more general test for `>=650` and there is no way to guarantee that specific values of `Days Old` will be in the query.

Answer (score 1):

First time I hear about CUBE, so you got me curious and I did some digging. Definitely not an expert, but here is what I found:

MDX language should allow you to provide value ranges in the form of `{[Table].[Field].[All].[LowerBound]:[Table].[Field].[All].[UpperBound]}`.

A. Get the total number of entries:

```
D3 =CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
           "[Measures].[Count of Docs]",
           "[EDD_Report].[Category_Name].&["&$B2&"]"),
           "{[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All]")
```

B. Get the number of entries less than 650:

```
E3 =CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
           "[Measures].[Count of Docs]",
           "[EDD_Report].[Category_Name].&["&$B2&"]"),
           "{[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All].[0]:[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All].[649]}")
```

Note I found something about using `.[All].[650].lag(1)}` but I think for it to work properly your data might need to be sorted?

C. Substract

```
C3 =D3-E3
```

Alternatively, go for the quick and dirty:

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",
           "[Measures].[Count of Docs]",
           "[EDD_Report].[Category_Name].&["&$B2&"]"),
           "{[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All].[650]:[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All].[99999]}")
```

Hope this helps and do let me know, I am still curious!

Comment: So the expression in step B did not work. However, I created a subset of the `Days Old` values using `=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","{[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[all].[650]:[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All].[3647]}")` . The cell containing this cubeset is referenced as the third `Member_expression` of the formula. The limitation is now that the values for the beginning and end must be members of the `Days Old` set. This is limiting, in that, I was hoping for a more general test for `>=650` .

Comment: Sorry just picking this up now. Are you saying that the max value must be an existing value, which is why you picked `.[All].[3647]`? Have you tried the `.Lag(1)` feature?

Comment: that is correct - 3647 is the maximum value. Will try `.Lag(1)` and report back.

Comment: In that case why not using `=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","{[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[all].[0]:[EDD_Report_10-01-18].[Days Old].[All].[649]}")` (i.e. values <650), or do you face the same problem? A walk around which I often use with pivot tables is to insert two additional items: one which would have `650 Days Old`, and one which would have `9999 Days Old`. Then you can use these two items as your boundaries, and substract 2 to the total count.